# Visio data linked to excel to update the shape text

Tags: vba, visio

I have used the native "Link Data to Shapes" feature in MS Visio however there is no way that I can get the shape text (i.e when you press F2 on a shape) to sync with a datafield.

The result is that I can visually hide the shape text when the data graphic is applied, however in the Visio file, the Shape texts are all unpopulated. I use a tool that imports the objects and is dependent on the shape text to be populated.

Is there any mechanism to sync the shape text to a custom property?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use Inert \ Field on your shape, and chose a Shape Data row to insert as a reference. In fact, you can insert multiple Data fields this way, if you so want to. You can also insert any other cell value and formulas.
See https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Insert-a-text-field-into-a-shape-0225c22e-3e5e-4ea7-9ca0-1ec91386cb1e for more information.